# nifi convert avro to json getting only single record

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Nifi 1.8 and trying a simple workflow

GenerateFlowFile -> ConvertRecord -> ConvertAvroToJSON

The generated flow file contains 5 lines but the view data provenance output claim in ConvertAvroToJSON shows only one line

Is it expected behaviour or did I make a mistake ?

My initial file in Generate workflow is

```
1,Millard,McKinley
2,Warren,Hoover
3,Dwight,Kennedy
4,Martin,Ford
5,Martin,Roosevelt
```

In Convert record I have 
a CSVRecordreader using ${avro.schema}
[cvsreader_properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIass.png)

a AvrRecordSetWriter using ${avro.schema}
[avro recordset writer properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObAF.png)

my variable avro.schema defines the Following schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "LongList",
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "id", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "lastname", "type": "string"}
  ]
}
```

I reuse the same schema text in my ConvertAvroToJson processor

[avrotojson schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUPAN.png)

I would expect to get 5 lines in the output of my pipeline
(output claim of avrotojson)

However I get only the first line:
[{"id": 1, "firstname": "Millard", "lastname": "McKinley"}]

Did I get Something wrong ?
Is this expected behaviour ?

One workaround is per line before hand but is there a way to do without splitting ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to go from CSV to Avro to Json, why not just use ConvertRecord with CSV reader and Json writer?

Comment: I plan to use record path based transformations before converting to json

Comment: Ok that doesn't really change anything... why not just use ConvertRecord with CSV reader and Json writer? There is no reason to convert to Avro.